# Should a contract define an abstracts methods?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, laravel-5

I have a repository that implements a contract. It also extends an abstract.

In the contract I have all of the repository's publicly available methods defined.

My question is, should the contract also define the abstracts publicly available methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a contract on your abstract say InterfaceA, and let the contract on your repository extend InterfaceA